# What does "shortlisting for this post is still in progress..." mean in the context of a UK job application?

Tags: application

I am trying to understand a message for an application in the UK that I received today. Here is the message ;

> The shortlisting for this post is still in progress, we hope to be
>   able to notify applicants of the final decision shortly.

This message is not clear to me. Does it mean that I am not shortlisted but longlisted? What should I understand from this message?

Comment: You should understand that they have not gotten down to a shortlist yet. That is still in progress. Once the short list is put together, they will let you know if you are on it.

Comment: @JonCuster. It should probably be an answer.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but in my mind it means that the applications are still on the Prof's desk and he hasn't looked at them yet....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The message means what it says. The shortlist hasn’t been decided yet. Whoever wrote you the message does not have more information to provide you at this time, or if they do, then they are not at liberty to provide it.

Any additional layers of interpretation that you choose to add to this message, such as inferring that you are longlisted, you add at your own risk. Certainly no one here can tell you whether such an interpretation is valid or not.

Good luck!